# Move items between two or more grid-stack containers

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, gridster

I would like to have two or more grid-stack (https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) containers and move the items (portlets) between them. How to register this containers, so the portlets can be moved from one to another container? And after that, how can I become the serialized positions for each container?

Example:

```
<div class="grid-stack" id="grid-nav-left"></div>
<div class="grid-stack" id="grid-body"></div>
<div class="grid-stack" id="grid-nav-right"></div>
```

Thanks!
Nik

Comment: Did you found out how to do it ??

Comment: You should try something yourself and then ask for help regarding any specific issue. Your current question is quite broad